# function infix to posfix doesn´t work properly

Tags: java

I have the next code which converts an aritmethic expression from infix to posfix,for example: 
2*(23+6)-1, in the function e the stack p already contains the expression

```
public static void e(){
        String exp;
        Stack<String> p = new Stack<String>();
        exp = posFija(p);
        System.out.println(" "+exp);
    }
```

and here is the two functions that are supposed to do the convertion:

```
public static String posFija(Stack<String> p){
        String posFix = "";
        Stack<String> temp = new Stack<String>();
        Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();      
        try
        {
            while(!p.isEmpty())
            {   
                switch(pref(p.peek())){
                    case 1:  
                       temp.push(p.pop());
                       break;
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                       while(pref(temp.peek()) >= pref(p.peek()))
                           s.push(t.pop());
                       temp.push(p.pop());
                       break;
                    case 2:
                       while(!temp.peek().equals("("))
                       {
                          s.push(temp.pop());
                       }
                       temp.pop();
                       p.pop();
                       break;
                    default:
                       s.push(p.pop());
                }
            }
            posFix = s.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return posFix;
    }
    private static int pref(String op) {
        int prf = 99;
        if (op.equals("^"))
           prf = 5;
        if (op.equals("*") || op.equals("/")) 
           prf = 4;
        if (op.equals("+") || op.equals("-")) 
           prf = 3;
        if (op.equals(")"))
           prf = 2;
        if (op.equals("("))
           prf = 1;
        return prf;
      }
```

The problem that i have is that when the switch finds the ")" (the expression was 2*(23+6)-1) it throws me the exception, and i don´t know how to fix this

Comment: In what order, stack p contains the expression.What does top of stack p contains,1 or 2? You haven't mentioned it here

Comment: Where `t` is declared, `s.push(t.pop());`

Comment: Which exception you are getting?

Comment: @Naman Gala sorry t is temp, the top stack contains 1 and the exception is Error

Comment: In catch block put this `ex.printStackTrace();` and post what exception you are getting.

Comment: it says EmptyStackException at java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown source)

Comment: I am trying to help you to debug your code. At which line this exception is coming. And try to find why it is coming.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the mistake is in the switch, in the case 3 and 4, because it doesn´t enter to the while(pref(temp.peek()) >= pref(p.peek())

Comment: What is the postfix expression for `2*(23+6)-1` and also EmptyStackException is getting throw because `temp.peek()` is trying to read top position of empty temp stack.

Comment: the postfix would be 2 23 6 + * 1 -

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work for it. Just check out what changes I have made in it.

```
public static void e() {
    String exp;
    Stack<String> p = new Stack<String>();
    // 2*(23+6)-1
    p.push("1"); //Pushing for right to left, or you can reverse stack in posFija if you are pushing from left to right
    p.push("-");
    p.push(")");
    p.push("6");
    p.push("+");
    p.push("23");
    p.push("(");
    p.push("*");
    p.push("2");

    exp = posFija(p);
    System.out.println(" " + exp);
}
```

Added empty check and last element of `temp` into `s`.

```
public static String posFija(Stack<String> p) {
    String posFix = "";
    Stack<String> temp = new Stack<String>();
    Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
    try {
        while (!p.isEmpty()) {
            switch (pref(p.peek())) {
            case 1:
                temp.push(p.pop());
                break;
            case 3:
            case 4:
                while (!temp.empty() && pref(temp.peek()) >= pref(p.peek())) //Empty check
                    s.push(temp.pop());
                temp.push(p.pop());
                break;
            case 2:
                while (!temp.peek().equals("(")) {
                    s.push(temp.pop());
                }
                temp.pop();
                p.pop();
                break;
            default:
                s.push(p.pop());
            }
        }
        //For last element in temp
        if (!temp.isEmpty() && !temp.peek().equals(")")) {
            s.push(temp.pop());
        }
        posFix = s.toString();
        //System.out.println("S: " + s);
        //System.out.println("P: " + p);
        //System.out.println("Temp: " + temp);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return posFix;
}
```

In `pref` method use `if-else if-else if` instead of `if-if-if`.

Comment: thanks i have found out what the problem is, when i have a expression like 5 + 6 y have to add the parenthesis (5 + 6) before i call the function posfija, i still have some issues but it now it works

Comment: According to Maths both the expression are different i.e. `5+6y` and `(5+6)y`. And if I answered your question then please accept it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, i did follow all the changes that you suggested and now the code is works perfectly, by the way it is only (5+6) and 5+6, the y was a mistake

Comment: For the expressions (i.e. (5+6) and 5+6 ) it is working. if I answered your question then please accept it.